"Add Polygonal Object" button does not appear on toolbar
I use QGIS 3.36.2 and I would like to create Polygon by drawing directly on the map. So I would like to use the "Add Polygonal Object" button while edit mode but there is no one on my toolbar.

Please edit your question to show some details about the layer you are editing (from the layer properties - information tab) and a screenshot of the "Digitizing toolbar".

Make sure you have the layer active/selected/highlighted in the layer tree
